# How to get the sum of all sections and subsections in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to determine how many pages I need for my toc which will be displayed in two coloumns with 10 (sub)sections each page.

So if I had 8 sections and 20 subsections the code should return 28.

*Edit:* If someone knows a solution with only one run it's highly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean the total number of frames???

Comment: No, I mean the total number of (sections + subsections)

Comment: Try the `totcount` package on the `section` and `subsection` counters and then add the numbers ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See the improved version below!!!**

**First**: Quick and dirty solution: This works, as long there are no `\chapter` commands, which reset the `section` counter.

However, the `subsection` counter is reset by `\section`: Either one drops the resetting or a special redefinition of `\subsection` is applied, using another totalsubsection counter.

After all, the value is stored in the counter variable `\mytotalcounter`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{mytotalcounter}

\begin{document}
\regtotcounter{section}
\regtotcounter{subsection}

\newcounter{totalsubsection}

\regtotcounter{totalsubsection}%

\let\BeamerSubsection\subsection

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{totalsubsection}%
\BeamerSubsection{#1}%
}%



\setcounter{mytotalcounter}{\totvalue{section}}
\addtocounter{mytotalcounter}{\totvalue{totalsubsection}}

There are \themytotalcounter~section units

\section{A}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{B}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{C}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{D}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{E}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{F}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{G}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}

\section{H}
\subsection{A1}
\subsection{A2}
\subsection{A3}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Improved version**

This does not redefine the `\subsection` command, but uses the `\pretocmd` macro from `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{totcount}%
\usepackage{forloop}%

\newcounter{mytotalcounter}%
\newcounter{totalsubsection}%

\regtotcounter{totalsubsection}%
\regtotcounter{section}%



\AtBeginDocument{%
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\refstepcounter{totalsubsection}}{\typeout{Yes, prepending was successful}}{\typeout{No, prepending was not it was successful}}%

\CalculateTotalSectionSubsection%
}%


\newcommand{\CalculateTotalSectionSubsection}{%
\setcounter{mytotalcounter}{\totvalue{section}}%
\addtocounter{mytotalcounter}{\totvalue{totalsubsection}}%
}%

\newcounter{loopsections}
\newcounter{loopsubsections}



\begin{document}

There are \themytotalcounter~(sub)section units
\forloop{loopsections}{1}{\number\value{loopsections} < 9}{%
\section{Section \Alph{loopsections}}
\forloop{loopsubsections}{1}{\number\value{loopsubsections} < 4}{%
\subsection{Subsection \Alph{loopsections}.\arabic{loopsubsections}}
}
}%

\end{document}
```

The output does not change, so I kept the old screen shot

Comment: Thank you, that works. Unfortunaly it requires two runs.

Comment: Almost anything connected to labels/counters within LaTeX requires two runs ;-)

Comment: Your redefinition of `\subsection` might be better; in its present form, you are suppressing the optional argument, so `\subsection[titleA]{titleB}` will produce undesired results.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I know, therefore I used the improved version. The first version was in a hurry

Comment: Thank you. I checked your improved version and it still needs two runs. I wouldn't have a problem with it, but I want to supply a theme and the users maybe wouldn't get this. I think it's possible because totalframenumber also just needs one run.

Comment: @TimS: I will take a look later on, but please provide such additional information earlier ;-)

Comment: @TimS: If you think of `\inserttotalframenumber`: It needs two runs too.

Comment: Thanks again, as far as I read it's not possible in one compilation , so it's all good now :-)

Comment: @TimS: Don't worry, even if you provide a theme, most TeX documents require at least two runs, so an experienced user will have issue with that. Happy TeXing! ;-)

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought about, too. Because my class has the `\inserttotalframenumber` command this should as you mentioned be the case.

Comment: @TimS: Sorry, I meant `should not have an issue with that`. Typing too fast ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually I read what you meant ;-)