# Progress bar in Berkeley theme

Tags: beamer, presentations

Here is my code below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
    \author{Anshul Sharma}
\title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.14\linewidth]{"CUHP LOGO"}
}
\institute{CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can i add a progress bar into it and also the logo of my university dosent fits well with the space in this theme.

Comment: What do you mean with "progress bar"? How should it look like and where should it be located? Please clarify.

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503702/beamer-how-to-add-progress-bar-with-section-titles?atw=1) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer/59749#59749) on how to add "progress bar" to your beamer. For your logo, you can adjust the width so that it places well at the top right.