# AtBeginSection without an extra page

Tags: beamer, presentations

I got this:

```
\newcounter{sectionsCounter}
\AtBeginSection[]{ %%% Use \AtBeginSection[]{ to ignore \section*
    \stepcounter{sectionsCounter}
    \begingroup
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=palette primary}

        \begin{frame}[plain,c]\label{sec-\thesectionsCounter}
            \usebeamerfont{section title}
            \begin{minipage}{.8\paperwidth}
                \color{section head color}
                \insertsection\\[1ex] %% = section name in section{}, \insertsectionhead = section[...]{} if set
                \progressbar{.25ex}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}

\AtBeginSubsection{
    \begingroup
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=palette primary}

        \begin{frame}[plain,c]
            \usebeamerfont{section title}
            \begin{minipage}{.8\paperwidth}
                \color{section head color}
                \insertsubsection\\[1ex]
                \progressbar{.25ex}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}
```

And I want the headings without an extra page if the section starts. I tried for hours now to achieve this, but I do not achieve it. Can maybe someone tell me what my problem is?
Since I want the header on the slides, but no extra page before the slides come. I do not see where my fault is. I tried to delete the line begin frame and minipage, but this messed it up.

Thanks in Advance

Here is an minimal example:
tex:

```
\documentclass[xetex,notheorems,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=true},xcolor={table}]{beamer}
\usetheme{minflat}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing,calc,arrows,positioning}

%%% enable notes on second screen
%\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
%\setbeamertemplate{note page}[compress]

    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define content of title page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\talkTitle{FakeWake}
\def\talkShortTitle{}
%\def\talkSubtitle{}
\def\talkKeywords{Keywords}

%% Define meta data of pdf
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Slides to talk - \talkTitle},
    pdfsubject={\talkTitle},
    pdfauthor={X Y},
    pdfkeywords={\talkKeywords},
    colorlinks=false
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    set content of title page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[\talkShortTitle]{\talkTitle}  
%\subtitle{\talkSubtitle} 
\author{X Y -- x.y@xy.ch}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}
\date{\DTMtoday}
\institute{%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{./gfx/uni_lu_logo_gr.jpg}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    theorem tools, theorem and proof styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\newcounter{chapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{dummyblock}{dummyblock}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\newenvironment<>{dummyblock}[1]{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=white}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=normal text.fg,bg=white}%
    \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}

\renewcommand\theta\vartheta


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    title page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    toc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    introduction
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    Hello
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Design}
\frametitle{Popular Smart Speakers}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Theme Options \& Remarks}
\frametitle{FakeWake}
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    Blocks, Alerts \& Math Environments
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Blocks, Alerts \& Math Environments}
\begin{frame}{Blocks, Alerts \& Math Environments}
\frametitle{minflat}
%   \begin{block}{Notation}
%       This is some notation.
%   \end{block}
%
%   \begin{definition}
%       This is a definition.
%   \end{definition}
%   
%   \begin{remark}
%       And this is a remark.
%   \end{remark}
%\end{frame}
%
%\begin{frame}
%   \begin{theorem}[Existence \& Uniqueness for ...]
%       A theorem is important so it should be emphasised!
%   \end{theorem}
%
%   \begin{proposition}
%       A proposition may be a little less important but it's also worth emphasising!
%   \end{proposition}
%   
%   In the same way we can create lemmata \& corollaries.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\label{slide::ex-alert-el}
    
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    Overlays \& Images
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Overlays \& Images}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Overlays \& Images}
    Hello
\end{frame}

%%%%    image frame with overlay left
%\imageFrameOverlayLeft{%
%./gfx/horizontallift.pdf}{%
%Want big impact?}{%
%Use a big picture.}

%%%%    image frame with overlay right, custom size
%\imageFrameOverlayRight[150pt]{%
%./gfx/horizontallift.pdf}{%
%Need a bigger overlay on the right side?}{%
%}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    Listings, Tables, Highlighted Text \& Tikz
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Listings, Tables, Highlighted Text \& Tikz}

\begin{frame}{Listings}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item $\sharp$1
        \item Item $\sharp$2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Subitem 2.$\sharp$1
                \item Subitem 2.$\sharp$2
            \end{itemize} 
    \end{itemize}
    and so on. We can also create highlighted lists:
    \begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
        \item \alert<4>{\only<-3>{Hi!}\only<4>{or here?}}
        \item you
        \item there!
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    highlighted frame with number and 
%%%%    optional subtext
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\highlightedFrame[such an impressive number should be big!]{89.432.567}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    conclusion frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Conclusion}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

sty1:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Copyright 2016-2017 Robert Baumgarth The project is hosted on                 %
%                                                                               %
%               https://github.com/vipowueb/minflat-beamer                      %
%                                                                               %
%   Version:    1.0                                                             %
%   Mail:       robert@tractatus.info                                           %
%   Website:        http://math.uni.lu/~baumgarth/,                                 %
%               http://robert.tractatus.info                                    %
%                                                                               %
% This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0     %
% International License (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).      %
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememinflat}[2015/11/17 Minimal Flat Design Beamer Theme]

\usefonttheme{minflat}
\usecolortheme{minflat}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    OPTIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\ifbeamer@nofooter
\beamer@nofooterfalse
\DeclareOptionBeamer{nofooter}{\beamer@nofootertrue}

\ProcessOptionsBeamer


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mode<presentation>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{20}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    load packages, format date
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    set beamer template elements
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bigcirc$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\circ$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$\circ$}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define title page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\titlepage{\usebeamertemplate{title page}}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
        \flushleft
        \vfill

        \ifx\insertinstitut\@empty%
        \else{%
            \vspace*{-6em}
            \usebeamerfont{institute}%
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{institute}%
            \insertinstitute \par
            \vspace*{6em}
        }%
        \fi%

        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else{%
            \usebeamerfont{subtitle}%
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}%
            \insertsubtitle \par
        }%
        \vspace*{.5em}
        \fi%

        \ifx\inserttitle\@empty%
        \else{%
            \usebeamerfont{title}%
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}% 
            \bfseries \inserttitle \par
        }%
        \vspace*{.5em}
        \fi%
                
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[beamergreen] (0, 0) -- (\textwidth, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \vspace*{1em}
        
        \ifx\insertauthor\@empty%
        \else{%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor \par
        }%
        \vspace*{.5em}
        \fi%

        \ifx\insertdate\@empty%
        \else{%
            \usebeamerfont{date}
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{date}
            \insertdate\par}%
        \fi%

        \vfill
        \vspace*{5mm}
    \end{minipage}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define thank you page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\origaddtocontents=\addtocontents
\def\dontaddtocontents#1#2{}

\newcommand\sectionNotInTocAndNavigation[1]{
    \let\addtocontents=\dontaddtocontents
    \section{#1}
    \let\addtocontents=\origaddtocontents
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define overlays
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{sectionsCounter}
\AtBeginSection[]{ %%% Use \AtBeginSection[]{ to ignore \section*
    \stepcounter{sectionsCounter}
    \begingroup
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=palette primary}

        \begin{frame}[plain,c]\label{sec-\thesectionsCounter}
            \usebeamerfont{section title}
            \begin{minipage}{.8\paperwidth}
                \color{section head color}
                \insertsection\\[1ex] %% = section name in section{}, \insertsectionhead = section[...]{} if set
                \progressbar{.25ex}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}

\AtBeginSubsection{
    \begingroup
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=palette primary}

        \begin{frame}[plain,c]
            \usebeamerfont{section title}
            \begin{minipage}{.8\paperwidth}
                \color{section head color}
                \insertsubsection\\[1ex]
                \progressbar{.25ex}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    set counter for progress bar
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtEndDocument{%
    \makeatletter
    \def\sp{ }%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \string\expandafter\string\ifx%
        \string\csname\sp c@schroedinger\string\endcsname\string\relax%
      \string\newcounter{\string schroedinger}%
      \string\fi%
      \string\setcounter{\string schroedinger}{\number\value{sectionsCounter}}%
    }%
}


\newcommand\progressbar[1]{%
    \dimen0=\textwidth
    \multiply\dimen0 by \insertframenumber
    \divide\dimen0 by \inserttotalframenumber
    \edef\progressbarwidth{\the\dimen0}
    \leavevmode%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=#1,dp=#1]{progress bar}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\progressbarwidth,ht=#1,dp=#1]{progress bar progress}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\calcProgressbar[3]{%
    \dimen1=\textwidth
    \multiply\dimen1 by #1%\insertframenumber
    \divide\dimen1 by #2%\inserttotalframenumber
    \advance \dimen1 by #3%-20pt
    \the\dimen1
%   \calcProgressbar{\the\frameNumber}{\the\totalFrameNumberWithoutThx}{20pt}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define progress bar header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{progressBarCounter}
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{flat header}{%
    \vspace*{.5em}
    
    \newcount\totalFrameNumberWithoutThx
    \totalFrameNumberWithoutThx=\inserttotalframenumber
    \advance \totalFrameNumberWithoutThx by -1
    
    \def\tmp@valx{\value{schroedinger}}%
        \ifnum\tmp@valx=-1%
        $??$%
    \else%
        \setcounter{progressBarCounter}{1}\relax\loop\ifnum\theprogressBarCounter<\theschroedinger%
            \def\getSectionLabel{sec-\theprogressBarCounter}
            \newcount\frameNumber
            \frameNumber=\getrefnumber{\getSectionLabel}%\getpagerefnumber{\getSectionLabel}
            \advance \frameNumber by 1
            \dimen1=\textwidth
            \multiply\dimen1 by \frameNumber
            \divide\dimen1 by \totalFrameNumberWithoutThx
            \advance \dimen1 by -20pt
            \edef\labelAlignmentWidth{\the\dimen1}
            \expandafter\edef\csname sectionWidth\the\value{progressBarCounter}\endcsname{\labelAlignmentWidth}
            \expandafter\edef\csname sectionTitle\the\value{progressBarCounter}\endcsname{\getSectionLabel}
            \stepcounter{progressBarCounter}\relax\repeat%
        \leavevmode%  

        \dimen0=\textwidth
        \multiply\dimen0 by \insertframenumber
        \divide\dimen0 by \totalFrameNumberWithoutThx
            \advance\dimen0 by -20pt
        \edef\slidesProgressbarWidth{\the\dimen0}
            
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={black!50!white,\labelAlignmentHelper,yshift=-4pt}]
            \draw[progressbar green] (0,0) -- (\slidesProgressbarWidth,0);
            
            \advance \value{schroedinger} by -1
            \foreach \i in {1,...,\theschroedinger} {
                \ifdim\csname sectionWidth\i \endcsname>345pt
                    \def\labelAlignmentHelper{below left}
                \else
                    \def\labelAlignmentHelper{below}
                \fi
            
                \ifnum\the\c@section=\i
                    \draw[draw=white,fill=progressbar green,thick] (\csname sectionWidth\i \endcsname,0) circle [radius=4pt];
                    \draw (\csname sectionWidth\i \endcsname,0) node[fill=white,font=\bfseries]{ \ \hyperlink{sec-\i}{\nameref{\csname sectionTitle\i \endcsname}} };
                \else
                    \draw[draw=progressbar green,fill=white] (\csname sectionWidth\i \endcsname,0) circle [radius=3pt];
                    \draw (\csname sectionWidth\i \endcsname,0) node[]{ \ \hyperlink{sec-\i}{\nameref{\csname sectionTitle\i \endcsname}} };            
                \fi
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    cut beamer symbols, define footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{flat footer}{
    \ifbeamer@nofooter\relax
    \else
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{nocolor}%{author in head/foot}%
                \color{lowOpacity}\hspace*{1.5em}\insertshortauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{nocolor}%{title in head/foot}%
                \color{lowOpacity}\hfill \insertframenumber\, \,(\inserttotalframenumber)\hspace*{1.5em}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
        \vskip1ex%
    \fi
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define image frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{blankframe}{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
}{}

\newcommand\imageFrame[1]{%
    \begin{blankframe}
        \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node[at=(current page.center)] {
                    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    \end{blankframe}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define image frames with overlay
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\imageFrameOverlay[5]{%
    \ifcase\pdfstrcmp{#5}{left}
        \def\xShift{}
        \def\anchorShift{west}
    \fi
    \ifcase\pdfstrcmp{#5}{right}
        \def\xShift{-}
        \def\anchorShift{east}
    \fi
    
    \begin{blankframe}
        \begin{frame}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,headNfoot/.style={section head color,text width=#1, align=center, xshift=\xShift#1/2}]
                \node[at=(current page.center)] {
                    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#2}
                };
                \draw [draw=none,fill=darkpurple,opacity=.8] (current page.north \anchorShift) rectangle ([xshift=\xShift#1]current page.south \anchorShift);
                \node[headNfoot] at ([yshift=-#1/3]current page.north \anchorShift) {\fontsize{26pt}{30pt}\selectfont\hyphenchar\font=-1 #3\par};
                \node[headNfoot] at ([yshift=#1/3]current page.south \anchorShift) {\bfseries\fontsize{26pt}{30pt}\selectfont\hyphenchar\font=-1 #4\par};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    \end{blankframe}
}

\newcommand\imageFrameOverlayLeft[4][125pt]{%
    \imageFrameOverlay{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{left}
}

\newcommand\imageFrameOverlayRight[4][125pt]{%
    \imageFrameOverlay{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{right}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    define highlighted frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\highlightedFrame[2][]{%
    \ifx#1\empty
        \def\highlightText{#1}
        \def\highlightSubText{}
    \else 
        \def\highlightText{#2}
        \def\highlightSubText{#1}
    \fi 
    
    \begingroup
        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=palette primary}

        \begin{frame}[plain,c]
            \usebeamerfont{section title}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node[at=(current page.center),text width=\textwidth,align=center] {
                    \color{section head color}
                    \bfseries\fontsize{48pt}{30pt}\selectfont\hyphenchar\font=-1 \highlightText\par
                    
                    \bfseries\fontsize{18pt}{30pt}\selectfont\hyphenchar\font=-1 \highlightSubText\par
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\milestones}[1]{%
    
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    redefine frame title
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
\vspace*{1em}
        \hspace*{-3pt}\color{darkpurple}{\insertframetitle}
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\textwidth,ht=1pt]{purple bar}
%       \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\mode
<all>

\linespread{.9}
```

st2

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Copyright 2016-2017 Robert Baumgarth The project is hosted on                 %
%                                                                               %
%               https://github.com/vipowueb/minflat-beamer                      %
%                                                                               %
%   Version:    1.0                                                             %
%   Mail:       robert@tractatus.info                                           %
%   Website:        http://math.uni.lu/~baumgarth/,                                 %
%               http://robert.tractatus.info                                    %
%                                                                               %
% This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0     %
% International License (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).      %
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\ProvidesPackage{beamerfontthememinflat}

\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setsansfont[Scale=.75,Ligatures={TeX},BoldFont={MuseoSans_500.otf}]{MuseoSans-300.otf}
%\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8,Scale=.7,vargreek-shape=unicode]{Asana Math}%XITS Math}
%\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8,Scale=.8,vargreek-shape=unicode]{XITS Math}
%\setmathfont[Scale=.7,range={\leq,\leqslant,\geq,\geqslant,\in,\notin,\subset,\subseteq,\subsetneq,\supset,\supseteq,\supsetneq,\subsetfin,\subsetcirc,\times,\otimes,\smwhtdiamond,\lhd,\rhd}]{XITS Math.otf}
%\setmathfont[Scale=.8,range={\mathbb}]{XITS Math.otf}
%\setmathfont[Scale=.8,range={\sum,\mathcal,\mathbfcal,\ell,\int}]{Euler-Math.otf}
\renewcommand\mathcal\mathscr
```

st3

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Copyright 2016-2017 Robert Baumgarth The project is hosted on                 %
%                                                                               %
%               https://github.com/vipowueb/minflat-beamer                      %
%                                                                               %
%   Version:    1.0                                                             %
%   Mail:       robert@tractatus.info                                           %
%   Website:        http://math.uni.lu/~baumgarth/,                                 %
%               http://robert.tractatus.info                                    %
%                                                                               %
% This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0     %
% International License (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).      %
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\ProvidesPackage{beamercolorthememinflat}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%    OPTIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\if@beamer@theme@purple
\@beamer@theme@purplefalse
\DeclareOptionBeamer{purple}{\@beamer@theme@purpletrue}

\ProcessOptionsBeamer


\if@beamer@theme@purple
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% define customary color theme
    %%% (red)purple
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \definecolor{darkpurple}{RGB}{137,57,94}
    \definecolor{beamergreen}{RGB}{57,137,100}
    \definecolor{beamerorange}{RGB}{255,175,0}
\else
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% define customary color theme
    %%% blue-violet
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \definecolor{darkpurple}{RGB}{76,61,122}%100,0,152}
    \definecolor{beamergreen}{RGB}{61,122,76}
    \definecolor{beamerorange}{RGB}{255,175,0}
\fi


\definecolor{progressbar green}{RGB}{150,198,23}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black!95!white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=beamerorange}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=beamergreen}

\definecolor{section head color}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=darkpurple}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=normal text.fg}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=darkpurple}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!85!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\definecolor{nocolor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{lowOpacity}{RGB}{110,110,110}
%\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}
%\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\colorbox{blue}{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}} 

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!85!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
%\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=normal text.bg!90!black}

\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted text,fg=white,bg=alerted text.fg}%!85!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!10!bg}

\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=white,bg=example text.fg!85!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}

\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar progress}{use=progress bar,bg=progressbar green}
\setbeamercolor{purple bar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}


\mode<all>
```

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal reproducible example

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Here you go

Comment: Urg, that theme is messy. I can't even get it to compile without making any modifications yet.

Comment: If you just want a progress bar with sections and are not forced to use that theme, I would rather use something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646696/36296